# Telegram Bot php keyboard array buttons dynamic

Tags: php, arrays, keyboard, telegram

I want create a Keyboard button list for Telegram bot. I use PHP but i have problem to create a multiarray.That i want any button for row and my script display all button at the one row. How i can jump the row for every button ?

My code is :

```
$llist = array();     
for($x=0;$x < 4; $x++)
{
$llist[]=["text"=>db_result($res,$x, 'club'),'callback_data' => 'Team ' .$x ];
} 
$list = array($llist);
$replyMarkup = array("keyboard" => $list,"resize_keyboard" => false,"one_time_keyboard" => false);     
$encodedKeyboard = json_encode($replyMarkup);
```

The code for static is :

```
$list = [
        'keyboard' => [
            [['text' => 'Team 1']],
            [['text' => 'Team 2']],
            [['text' => 'Team 3']],
            [['text' => 'Team 4']]
        ]
    ];

    $encodedKeyboard = json_encode($list);
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

To display buttons on top of each other every button needs to be represented by it's own array.

To generate your static code dynamically try this:

```
$list = array();
for($x=0;$x < 4; $x++)
{
    array_push($list, array(["text"=>db_result($res,$x, 'club'),'callback_data' => 'Team ' .$x]));
}
$replyMarkup = array("keyboard" => $list,"resize_keyboard" => false,"one_time_keyboard" => false);
$encodedKeyboard = json_encode($replyMarkup);
```